# No resource found error implementing Material Design In Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Following this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

I get this error:

```
error is #Error:(11, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
#Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\hamees\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: i have done this process but same error

Comment: set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` then remove `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: whats your `minSdkVersion`

Comment: check your dependencies first.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya minsdk 15

Comment: @DevendraSingh what i have to check for ?

Answer (score 0):

The style you are using is for lower versions.

For **API 21** and greater -

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
 <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```